# rosrun cant find package when using catkin_make_isolated

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosrun, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
when i use catkin_make_isolated, i can build executable successfully.
but i cant use "rosrun package_name xxx" to execute it.
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named xxx below /home/xxx/catkin_ws/src/package_name

the executable is /home/xxx/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/package_name/lib/package_name/xxx.
how can i execute it using rosrun?

thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327904/rosrun-cant-find-package-when-using-catkin_make_isolated./) by [siyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37396/siyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, you can navigate to the catkin_ws

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
```

then,

```
source ./devel_isolated/setup.bash
```

then you can try doing rosrun again.

---

Originally posted by [GabrielBagon44](https://answers.ros.org/users/42069/gabrielbagon44/) with karma: 60 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GabrielBagon44](https://answers.ros.org/users/42069/gabrielbagon44/) on 2019-07-08**:
if this doesn't work you might have to check if you have added it as an executable